# WebHDFS's redirection URL to datanode has unresolvable local hostname when on AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, dns, hdfs, webhdfs

I have HDFS running on an EC2 node (pseudo multi-node setup) and I use it to access files via the WebHDFS's REST API by doing a GET at e.g. this:

> http: slash slash ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/foo/bar.txt?op=OPEN

This gives me a temporary redirect to

> http: slash slash ip-yy-yy-yy-yy.us-west-2.compute.internal:50075/webhdfs/v1/foo/bar.txt?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=localhost:9000&offset=0

Here *xx-xx-xx-xx* is the public, static IP assigned to my instance and *yy-yy-yy-yy* is the local ip for the instance.

This makes the redirect fail because *ip-yy-yy-yy-yy.us-west-2.compute.internal* cannot be opened from the browser, obviously! I would want the redirect URL generated to have the static, public IP assigned to my instance, resolvable by the default public DNS.

[Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs-default.html) is the list of HDFS configuration defaults but I can't understand what is causing this situation.

My hdfs-site.xml configs:

```
dfs.replication: 1
dfs.webhdfs.enabled:true
```

My core-site.xml configs:

```
fs.defaultFS: hdfs://localhost:9000
```

Any sort of help is appreciated, thanks!